# Custom fields for custom block in shopware 6

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-api

I'm making a custom block in Shopware 6, the point is that I need to add a couple of custom fields to it so that they can affect the design. But I didn't understand how it can be done.

```
Shopware.Service('cmsService').registerCmsBlock({
    name: 'my-image-text-reversed',
    category: 'text-image',
    label: 'My Image Text Block!',
    component: 'sw-cms-block-my-image-text-reversed',
    previewComponent: 'sw-cms-preview-my-image-text-reversed',
    defaultConfig: {
        marginBottom: '20px',
        marginTop: '20px',
        marginLeft: '0px',
        marginRight: '0px',
        sizingMode: 'boxed'
    },
    slots: {
        left: 'text',
        right: 'image'
    }
});
```

You need to add 8 custom fields. It's either progress scrolling or just numbers. These fields should be set to their default values.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom element and then you can link it to your slots in the custom block. Here’s a link to the documentation: https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/content/cms/add-cms-element

**Edit**
Within a custom CMS block you can use the default Shopware elements like text, image, form, product-box etc...

If these elements aren't enough because you've got other requirements, then you can create your own CMS element. When creating your own element you can add the components you need. Which components are available can be found here: https://component-library.shopware.com/

Once you're done with setting up your own element, you can add it to your slot in your custom CMS block.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).